# How to download .7z file with FTP

Tags: browser, download, ftp, archive

I want to access this archive file :

ftp://Admin_Express_ext:Dahnoh0eigheeFok@ftp3.ign.fr/ADMIN-EXPRESS_3-1__SHP__FRA_WM_2022-02-17.7z

(found on this page : https://geoservices.ign.fr/adminexpress )

Though it seems that the File Transfer Protocol might be used to proceed to the download and I don't figure out how it works on a web browser. How can I access the file then ?

Answer (score -1):

In FileZilla, paste the name of the domain (in this case ftp://ftp3.ign.fr/) in the host box.

After a few seconds you'll be connected to the remote server where the files are located.

The files are located in the bottom right panel, simply drag and drop the file at the place you've chosen on your computer (bottom left panel).